# In which method of ViewGroup should I perform modification of the layout of its subviews?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Please Note: I'm creating everything programmatically, so I'm not looking anywhere to mingle with the LayoutInflater service or its tricks. Because at the base, I do not want to create a single layout.xml of what I want to achieve here.

Let's say I have a RelativeLayout and I've added a TextView and ImageView on this layout. Now, I want to know which method should I override where the RelativeLayout has already completed developing its final dimensions and which I can use to perform layout modifications of the TextView and ImageView.

I've tried many methods like overriding onLayout, onMeasure, onAttachedToWindow, etc.
I also tried attaching the onGlobalLayoutListener on the ViewTreeGroup of RelativeLayout and tried setting the layoutParams of its subviews. But, I can use this observer only once and then I've to remove it otherwise it gets called 2,000 times every 3 seconds.

But nothing seems to work properly.

Can anyone shed some light onto achieving this ?

Note2 : Kindly do not comment as "what have you tried so far?". I've tried many things as I said before, and I cannot paste all what I've tried. But still I'll give an important information on how I'm modifying the layoutParams of a view so that you can get an idea.

```
RelativeLayout rl = //assumed generated programmatically.

TextView tv  = //assumed generated programmatically.

rl.setPadding(0,0,0,0); //i remove all the padding 
rl.addView(tv);

//now once added I modify its layoutParams

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)tv.getLayoutParams();
rlp.leftMargin = rl.getWidth() - 100;
rlp.width = 100;
rlp.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

//thats and I do the above in an overridden method of RelativeLayout and expect the TextView to appear at the right-most end with width 100 and height equal to the container layout's height.
```

Further, overriding onLayoutParams of RelativeLayout works, but it doesn't work properly for tableView cells. Here's an example

```
//Definition of custom RelativeLayout

public class MyRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout
{
    TextView tv;

    public MyRelativeLayout(Context context)
    {
       super(context);

       tv = new TextView(context);

       this.addView(tv);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        super.onLayout(changed,l,t,r,b);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)tv.getLayoutParams();
       rlp.width = 100;
       rlp.leftMargin = this.getWidth() - 100;
       rlp.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    }
}

  //implementation of MyRelativeLayout as a cell in listView
 public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
 {
    MyRelativeLayout rl = (MyRelativeLayout)view;
    if(rl==null)
    {
       rl = new MyRelativeLayout(viewGroup.getContext());

       rl.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
       rl.setMinimumHeight(100); //this is another useless special 
       //method of android that I've to always write to set the height 
       //of cell. Adding of layoutParams to define the cell size just 
       //won't work.

     //Even though all this is done, the new cells that are visible in the 
     //list view on scroll will have improper size of textView, either the 
     //height is totally zero, or sometimes half the height of its layout, 
     //sometimes left aligned, sometimes right aligned. 

    }

    return rl;
 }
```

Comment: First of all, there good tools to align element at the right in relative Layout:
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT);
This code will align child at the rigth. Your code is invalid because rl.getWidth return 0, I think. It's incorrect to use getWidth, because it filled only after measurement and layout.

Comment: I do not want just a simple right alignment. the example I gave it just one way to get the customisation of subview, however, I'll be doing more complex stuffs, which are beyonds the static rules of android's enumeration.

Comment: Oh, ok. If you want to do a lot of really complex stuff with positioning of childs inside relative layout, you may to override Relative layout and override layout(int l, int t, int r, int b) method. Inside this method you must manually position all childs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#layout(int, int, int, int).
Or if you don't want to override RL and don't need to do really complex stuff, you can do it inside onGlobalLayoutListener, but use getMeasuredWidth instead of getWidth

Comment: But be carefully. It's not good idea to change layoutparams frequently, because it will calls measure, layout, draw. It's very expensive operation.

Comment: I tried overriding onLayout. works! but, this same doesn't work on the cells of ListView that I create in getView. Hence, I am looking for some universal method which works everywhere for layout. In ListView when the new cell is visible then the subviews of this newly appeared cell are all haphazard, even though the onLayout is overridden. :( I'll show an example above in my question.

Comment: I make mistake. Inside onLayout you must write this code. Inside this method you don't need to call super.onLayout() and don't need to change layout params of child. Inside this method you must set position of child. Look at the source code of FrameLayout for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now i see your mistake. You mustn't change layout params inside onLayout method. It will be calling recoursivly and don't have desired effect. You must write something like this inside:

```
 @Override
public void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
{
   tv.layout(r - 100, t, r, b);
}
```

This code will positioning element inside your relative layout. At this moment your child already have measured width. When your change layout params you must call measure, layout and after measure again.
Or you can have some more complex logic here to specify position of your element.

Comment: but, you're calling super.onLayout in this method. You said don't call super.onLayout then why here ?

Comment: sorry, i copy pasted from your code. You don't need it here. But you must call layout for all childs.

Comment: great! seems like I have a solution now. I'll implement this soon and see if it works. Thank you very much for helping me out.. :)

Comment: But I really don't think that you need to do this =). I think that static rules of RelativeLayout is enough for most tasks. Can you apply an image with desired result. And describe why you don't want to use inflaters and want to create everything programmatically. In most cases it's now a good way. I see, you are iOS developer. In android it's a easier a lot to use xml and inflaters rather in iOS =)

Comment: Yes, I'm a mainstream iOS developer and I find myself comfortable in doing everything programmatically. My philosophy behind doing this is that if I need to set the view to screen at x = 10, then I should just be able to set it to 10, rather than knowing numerous enumerations and finding a way to achieve 10 out of those. :D

Comment: I see. In Android in most cases you can't set this element on screen at 10 =). There are a lot of screen sizes, densities and aspect ratios. 10px on different screens looks different. That's why in android several types of layouts with it's own rules and very complex mechanism to measure and layout. Using size in pixel - bot good, better way to use dp. Look here http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html. There are some lessons about ui in android.

Comment: And one more. Design UI in xml in android is very flexible tool. I have built very complex UI with RelativeLayout, which looks good on every phone and everything was written in xml =).

Comment: That's great to know that you can develop complex UI using standard process of Android. :) I tried your suggestion, it works, life is easy now.. :)